# Pandas DataFrame - How to set multiple columns from object at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `class Features()` which is a calculator for multiple features. It takes a domain like 'google.com' and sets different properties like `tld`,`sld`,`sld_length` etc. I also have a dataframe with column `domain`.

```
class Features():
    def __init__(domain):
        ....
        # split domain and do some calculations
        # set attributes
```

I need to add another columns based on `domain` Series. For this I want to use `Features` class which calculates some properties from `domain` (as a string).

For every row in the dataframe, I would like to instantiate the class just once.

How to do that?

Right now, I have to do this.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(MY_CSV_WITH_DOMAINS)

df['sld'] = df['domain'].apply(lambda x: Features(x).sld)
df['sld_length'] = df['domain'].apply(lambda x: Features(x).sld_length)
```

Which instantiates the class multiple times, so multiple times it has to calculate all properties.

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @anky_91 I've edited the question. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create dictionary with instances of `Features` for each unique `domain`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'domain':[1, 3, 42, 3, 42]})

class Features():
    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.sld = domain**2
        self.sld_length = len(str(self.sld))

F = {d: Features(d) for d in df['domain'].unique()}

df['sld'] = df['domain'].apply(lambda x: F[x].sld)
df['sld_length'] = df['domain'].apply(lambda x: F[x].sld_length)

print(df)

   domain   sld  sld_length
0       1     1           1
1       3     9           1
2      42  1764           4
3       3     9           1
4      42  1764           4
```

Re-reading the question, I see that the domains may all be different, in which case you do not need `unique()` above.